# How to see status of a command called in newgrp?

Tags: shell, recursion, csh

I have a csh script that needs to use newgrp for part of its run. To this end, it recursively calls itself.

```
#!/bin/csh
if ( $1 == "" ) then
    newgrp << ENDGRP
    ./newgrp_test.csh 2
    if ( $status != 0 ) then
        echo "Second run fail"
        exit 1
    else
        echo "Second run success"
        exit 0
    endif
ENDGRP
    if ( $status != 0) then
        echo "Exiting failure"
        exit 1
    else
        echo "Exiting success"
        exit 0
    endif
endif

if ( $1 == "2" ) then
    exit 1
endif
```

The problem is I think it should be guaranteed to fail, but I'm getting successful output. My output looks like this:

```
Second run success
Exiting success
```

Why can I not read the status of the the script within the newgrp?

Note I have found a workaround by removing the if block between newgrp and ENDGRP, but I'm still curious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable `$status` is being expanded by the outer shell inside the here document. So when the `newgrp`-spawned shell runs it is seeing `if ( 0 != 0 ) then` and not `if ( $status != 0 ) then` (because the `if`, or whatever`was successful immediately before the`newgrp` command).

You either need to escape the `$` in the here document:

```
if ( \$status != 0 ) then
```

or quote part of the here document word to prevent expansion from happening entirely:

```
    newgrp << 'ENDGRP'
    ./newgrp_test.csh 2
    if ( $status != 0 ) then
        echo "Second run fail"
        exit 1
    else
        echo "Second run success"
        exit 0
    endif
'ENDGRP'
```